# Codeigniter password matches not working with md5

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I use the following code in a validation form the password matches do not match the two passwords even when the two passwords are same.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5|trim|xss_clean|matches[rpassword]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rpassword','Repeat Password','required|md5|trim|xss_clean');
```

But when I remove the md5 function then the password matches is working properly.

Can someone understand why this happens?

Comment: Call it a *blessing in disguise*. MD5 is old and considered broken. For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do matches[rpassword], it's looking at the current value of password after the md5 but rpassword before the md5.

Switch it to this so that it does the match validation BEFORE converting to md5:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|matches[rpassword]|md5|trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rpassword','Repeat Password','required|md5|trim|xss_clean');
```

Also, if this is an application where security truly matters - please know that md5 is very easy to crack and that if someone is able to ever get into your database that they **will** be able to hack all of these passwords. So basically using md5 is almost the equivalent to not encrypting in the first place.

For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Perfect! Now is working! Thank you! What are you suggest me for security?

Comment: Fred's comment is spot on for that - PHP 5.5's password_hash and password_verify functions, or the compatibility pack if you have an older version of PHP will give you those methods.

Comment: If those rules are run in order, then `trim` should also be before `md5`, and `xss_clean` is probably   redundant, since the output of `md5` will only ever consist of 0 to 9 and a to f.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the operation do comparation of "matches[rpassword]"  it is before of variable "rpassword" be found, see below:

Your code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5|trim|xss_clean|matches[rpassword]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rpassword','Repeat Password','required|md5|trim|xss_clean');
```

Updated and working:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|md5|trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rpassword','Repeat Password','required|md5|trim|xss_clean|matches[password]');
```